# Unable to send response from PHP to ajax JS file without it being empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, string, response

I am trying to send a string containing type of error that user might encounter during logging in from login.php to signin.ajax.js file so the URL could be tailored according to the type of error

this is the login.php file

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    
    $name = $data->username;
    $password = $data->password;

    // Instantiate LoginContr class
    include '../classes/LoginController.class.php';
    $login = new LoginController($name, $password);

    // Running error handlers and user handlers
    $login->loginUser();
    
    if ($login->getError()) {
        $response = ['error' => $login->getError()];
    } else {
        $response = ['success' => 'Logged in successfully'];
    }

    

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

this is the signin.ajax.js file

```
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login");

loginButton.addEventListener('click', loginUser);

function loginUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let username = document.getElementById("login-username").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("login-password").value;
    let loginParams = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }
    let jsonString = JSON.stringify(loginParams);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "../includes/login.php", true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            let response;
            try {
                // Check if the response is not empty before parsing
                if (xhr.responseText.trim() !== "") {
                    response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                } else {
                    console.log("Empty response");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error parsing JSON:", error);
                return;
            }
        
            if (response.error) {
                // Handle the error
                window.location.href = "../pages/loginRegister.page.php?error=" + encodeURIComponent(response.error);
            } else if (response.success) {
                // No error, successful login
                window.location.href = "../pages/loginRegister.page.php";
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown response format");
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Request failed. Status: " + xhr.status);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(jsonString);
}
```

this is the LoginController.class.php class

```
<?php

include 'LoginModel.class.php';


class LoginController extends LoginModel
{

    private $name;
    private $password;
    private $error;

    public function __construct($name, $password)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->error = null;
    }

    public function loginUser(){
        if($this->emptyInputUsernameAndPassword() == false)
        {
            $this->error = 'emptyInputUsernameAndPassword';
        }
        if($this->emptyInputUsername() == false){
            $this->error = 'emptyInputUsername';
        }
        if($this->emptyInputPassword() == false)
        {
            $this->error = 'emptyInputPassword';
        }
        
        $this->getUser($this->name, $this->password);
    }
    

    private function emptyInputUsername()
    {
        if (empty($this->name)) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function emptyInputPassword()
    {
        if (empty($this->password)) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function emptyInputUsernameAndPassword()
    {
        if (empty($this->name) && empty($this->password)) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getError() {
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

I tryed various console logs, try catch blocks and i allways get the same output that the response is empty.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {` will never be true in login.php, because your XHR code only sends "username" and "password" fields, not a "signin" field. Also you're sending that username and password data in JSON format, so it will never put _anything_ into the `$_POST` array anyway. And of course if the code doesn't enter that `if` block, then the script just stops, which will of course then result in an empty response back to the browser.

Comment: You need to send signin value or parameter to the login.php, so server will read the rest